# Open Kendo Prompt Customized dialog on button click

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, dialog, prompt

I have tried to piece together bits of info from google searches, but I can't find a clear answer to why the Kendo Prompt only works once when a page is refreshed.  Here is a simple script which is based on one of the samples provided by Telerik, but I modified it to allow the prompt to be triggered by  a button click.  It appears that after the click, the prompt div is no longer accessible, but I don't understand why. Anybody know the answer?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="prompt"></div>
<div><button class="k-button" onclick="onClk()">Click Here</button></div>
<script>
  function onClk() {
      $("#prompt").kendoPrompt({
      content: "Prompt text",
     value: "Default input text",
    messages:{
      okText: "OK"
    }
    }).data("kendoPrompt").result.done(function(data){
        console.log("User accepted with text: " + data);
    })
    .fail(function(data){
        console.log("User rejected with text: " + data);
    });
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just posted an answer for you. please look at it if it works for you.

Comment: hey @Paul can you select the answer as correct if this worked for you, so that others having the same issue might also get benefit

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam - Your reply was the correct answer.  I left a comment below the original response last month.  Not sure what else I need to click to make that clear to others.

Comment: :) you just need to select it as correct, the **TICK MARK** with green color. you just need to click it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are using customized prompts targetted to a container rather than normal alert and prompt dialogs, and after opening it for the first time, once you click on `ok` or `cancel` the container `div` `#prompt` is removed from the document along with the dialog, and when you click the button again to open it, it simply does not find the element to bind `kendoprompt`so it throws the error at the point when it calls `.data()`. ideally, if you want to use it in this way you should create the container `div` before calling the function inside your `javascript` and append it to the body, change your code to match the below code in the demo. just match your javascript and try to use meaningful names for the functions.

Hope it helps

```js
function myPrompt() {
  $("#prompt").kendoPrompt({
      content: "Prompt text",
      value: "Default input text",
      messages: {
        okText: "OK"
      }
    }).data("kendoPrompt").result.done(function(data) {
      console.log("User accepted with text: " + data);
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
      console.log("User rejected with text: " + data);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".k-button").on('click', function() {
    if ($("#prompt").length < 1) {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.setAttribute('id', 'prompt');
      $('body').append(div);
    }
    myPrompt();
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="prompt"></div>
  <div>
    <button class="k-button">Click Here</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  That did the trick.  Javascript is not my native language, and some of its quirks are not particularly intuitive.